# Сортировка массива структуры

Tags: c++, массивы, структуры, fstream

У меня есть структура

```
struct AirData {
    string marka_LA;
    string bortovoyNomer;
    int nomerReica;
    char vremayPosadki[6];
};
```

Так же текстовый файл из которого я запалняю эту структуру , который имеет вид:

```
марка  б.номер номер рейса время посадки 
 ТУ-154 Б-373   1763         23:35
 ВВ-213 В-132   393          23:38
 ВВ-123 в-213   3422         -09:32 
 Дд-231 ы-123   2321         -12:23
 Rw-123 as-12   2321         32:23
```

функция сортировки :

```
void swap_base(AirData &t1, AirData &t2) {   // функция для сотировки
    AirData tmp;
    tmp = t2;
    t2 = t1;
    t1 = tmp;
}






int main() {
    int N = 0; // количество строк
    string line;
    fstream file;
    file.open(fileName);

    // считываем кол-во строк
    if (file.is_open()){
        while (getline(file, line)) {
            N++;
        }
    }
    file.close();
    AirData base[N]; // Массив структуры данных

    file.open(fileName);
    if (file.is_open()){
        while (!file.eof()) {
            getline(file, line, ch);
            for (int j = 0; j < N; j++){
                for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++){
                    if (i == 0) {
                        file >> base[j].marka_LA;

                    }
                    if (i == 1) {
                        file >> base[j].bortovoyNomer;
                    }
                    if (i == 2) {
                        file >> base[j].nomerReica;
                    }
                    if (i == 3) {
                        file >> base[j].vremayPosadki;
                    }

                }
            }

        }
```

я заполняю массив струтуры, а дальше мне нужно отсортировать и вывести на экран по такому правилу: если время посадки >= 0, то сортировать по этому времени, если же < 0 , то сортировать по номеру рейса. не получается правильно оформить обработку

```
for (int i = 0; i < N; i++) {
    for(int j = i + 1; j < N; j++) {
        for(int v = 0; v < 6; v++){
            if (base[i].vremayPosadki[v] >= base[j].vremayPosadki[v])
                swap_base(base[i], base[j]);
        }
    }
}


// Если самолет в воздухе ( время меньше 0)
for (int k = 0; k < N; k++){

    if (base[k].vremayPosadki[0] == '-'){ // если время <0 то производим сортиоровку по номеру рейса хорошо)
        for (int i = k; i < N; i++) {
            for(int j = i + 1; j < N; j++) {
                if (base[i].nomerReica > base[j].nomerReica)
                    swap_base(base[i], base[j]);
            }
        }

    }
}

    for( int i=0; i< N;i++) {
        cout <<"marka_LA: "<< base[i].marka_LA <<" bortovoyNomer: "<<base[i].bortovoyNomer<<" nomerReica: "<<base[i].nomerReica<<" vremayPosadki: "<<base[i].vremayPosadki<<endl;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Если вы не против, напишу с оптимизацией вашего кода:

```
struct AirData {
    string marka_LA;
    string bortovoyNomer;
    int nomerReica;
    int vremayPosadki[2];    // использовать время в виде чисел удобней
};
```

также можно  время посадки хранить в обьекте `std::pair<int>`
(`23:35` можно считывать как `23` и `35`)
  Для того, чтобы упростить код, уменьшить количество циклов и повторений выражений, сначала определим оператор ввода для вашей структуры:

```
istream& operator >>(istream& is, AirData& air)
{
    is >> air.marka_LA >> air.bortovoyNomer >> air.nomerReica >> air.vremayPosadki[0];
    is.ignore();                     // пропускаем символ ':'
    is >> air.vremayPosadki[1];      // считываем минуты
    return is;
}
```

Теперь определим компараторы:

```
bool cmpToFlight(const AirData &a1, const AirData &a2)
{
    return a1.nomerReica < a2.nomerReica;
}
bool cmpToTime(const AirData& a1, const AirData& a2)
{
    if(a1.vremayPosadki[0] == a2.vremayPosadki[0])
        return a1.vremayPosadki[1] < a2.vremayPosadki[1];
    return a1.vremayPosadki[0] < a2.vremayPosadki[0];
}
```

Теперь можно написать простенький код:

```
int main()
{ 
    // здесь ваш код, где вы определили количество строк в файле  
    //так как на первой строчке у вас  ярлыки, а не рейсы, прочтем ее 
    // как отдельную строку, а для рейсов будет на одну единицу меньше строк
    AirData base[N - 1];
    string s;
    getline(file, s);
    // благодаря написаноому нами оператору, легко введем обьекты структуры
    for (int i = 0; i < N - 1; ++i)
        file >> base[i];
    std::sort(base, &base[N], cmpToTime);
   // после этой сортировки, обьекты с полем отрицательной времени, будут 
   первыми  
   //найдем где конец таких и отсортируем по первому компаратору 
    int k = 0;
    while (base[k].vremayPosadki[0] < 0) ++k;   
    std::sort(base, &base[k], cmpToFlight);
    // проверим результат 
    cout << s << endl;
    for (int i = 0; i < N - 1; ++i)
        cout << base[i].marka_LA <<' ' << base[i].bortovoyNomer <<' '
             << base[i].nomerReica <<' ' << base[i].vremayPosadki[0] <<':'
             << base[i].vremayPosadki[1] << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Не так уж трудно, когда логически раставляешь шаги. Конечно всегда можно написать и получше, но главное не размазать код разной ерундой... Желаю удачи!

Comment: Да, забыл отметить, что обычно осуществляют проверку корректности содержания файла, но если вы уверены, что там все в порядке, можете не писать код проверки